# How to filter records using hasMany association

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to figure out what should be a simple solution: filterBy records using an array of hasMany ids.

I have a model `Language`, which `hasMany` `Provider`s, and vice versa. From a collection of `Provider`s, I need to `filterBy('language', [1,2])` or even `filterBy('language', 2)`.

(I can't do a language.get('providers') since I'd getting the collection of Providers from another association.)

```
// models.language.js
var Language = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  providers: DS.hasMany('provider')
});

// models/provider.js
var Provider =  DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    region: DS.belongsTo('region', { async: true }),
    languages: DS.hasMany('language', {async: true})
}); 

// In this region-component.js I have the model title, 
// and then an each block listing all providers
// When the language filter changes, I need it to filter down
// just to those providers who have the language association.
providers: function() { 
    return this.get('model').get('providers').filterBy('languages', this.get('language'));
}.property('model')
```

Answer (score 0):

`filterBy` filters based on a single property, but you can just use `filter` itself, passing it a selection function:

```
filteredProviders: function() {
  let providers = this.get('providers');   // some providers to select from
  let languages = this.get('languages');   // array of languages to select

  // Does a provider have one of the languages we're looking for?
  function providerHasLanguage(provider) {
    return provider.get('languages') . 
      some(language => languages.indexOf(language) !== -1;
  }

  return providers . filter(providerHasLanguage);
}.property('providers', 'languages')
```

Answer (score 0):

So some redditors helped me out and I worked it from there. Seems there is no native solution but to iterate through each array and render a new array from matching objects.

```
// app/utils/where.js
let where = function(sourceArray, property, language_id) {
  let destArray = [];

  sourceArray.forEach(function(obj) {
    obj.get(property).forEach(function(property_object) {
      let id = parseInt(property_object.get('id'));
      if (language_id === id) {
        destArray.push(obj);
      }
    });
  });
  return destArray;
}

export default where;
```

And its usage:

```
// in a component
import where from 'path';

let filteredProviders =  where(providers, 
    'languages', language_id);
```

Minor modifications would be required to accommodate filtering from an array of multiple language_ids.